# Automatically merge unregistered account with existing account when using same email

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, merge-accounts, unregistered-users

I asked a question on engineering.stackexchange.com before joining the site, and provided my email. Unfortunately, I used a different name than my username on the Stack Exchange network. Still, the unregistered user had my avatar without me having indicated which avatar to use.

I later joined the site, and expected the question to be associated with my account rather than with a separate unregistered account - but that didn't happen. Alternatively, I should have at least been offered the option to make the association. Why doesn't that happen?

Notes:

- I'm asking why this doesn't happen for *everyone* and in *general*, I'm not asking about my specific case.
- Since my accounts have now been merged (following an explicit request with a contact form) I've dropped the links. The general question remains of course.